# {{variable}} not interpreted

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

Somehow my variable that is placed inside `{{color}}` and `{{avatar}}` is not interpreted/swapped with actual content. See example below:

```
<paper-toolbar id="navheader" class="tall">
   <div class="middle avatar {{color}}" style="background-image: url({{avatar}})"></div>
   <div class="bottom uuid">{{uuid}}</div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

If I instead put the color-variable where `uuid` is, it will print the correct `color`, meaning it's not that the variable isn't being set or isn't `published`. It seems that the `"`-characters are somehow interfering, am I doing something wrong? Might be worth mentioning that this is done in the "main" document.

Full code below:

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsive-width="1280px">
<div class="nav" drawer>
        <paper-toolbar id="navheader" class="tall">
            <div class="middle avatar {{color}}" style="background-image: url({{avatar}})"></div>
            <div class="bottom uuid">{{uuid}}</div>
        </paper-toolbar>


    <section class="layout vertical" id="onlineList">
        <paper-item label="Online Now" class="subdue layout horizontal center"></paper-item>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{cats}}" as="cat">
            <paper-item label="{{cat}}"></paper-item>
        </template>
    </section>
</div>

<paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall">

<paper-toolbar>
        <div class="flex">Kitteh Anonymous</div>
        <iron-icon icon="account-circle"></iron-icon><span>{{occupancy}}</span>
</paper-toolbar>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="layout vertical fit" id="chat">
        <div class="chat-list flex">
        <!--<x-chat-list avatar="url" username="name" text="hello" status="online" timestamp="1420145273945"></x-chat-list>-->
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{messageList}}" as="message">
                <x-chat-list color="{{message.color}}" avatar="{{message.avatar}}" username="{{message.uuid}}" text="{{message.text}}" status="{{message.status}}" timestamp="{{message.timestamp}}"></x-chat-list>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="shim"></div>

        <div class="send-message layout horizontal">
            <paper-input class="flex" label="Type message..." id="input" value="{{input}}" on-keyup="checkKey"></paper-input>
            <paper-fab icon="send" id="sendButton" on-tap="sendMyMessage"></paper-fab>
        </div>
</div>
</paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Answer (score 3):

String concatenation is not supported in 1.0 as it was before, though it is being worked on last I heard.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content

You will have to create a method which performs the concatenation for you, and bind to that method instead.

Example:

```
<div class$="{{_colorClass(color)}}" style$="{{_backgroundImage(avatar)}}"></div>

<script>
  Polymer({
    _colorClass: function(color) {
      return 'middle avatar '+color;
    },
    _backgroundImage: function(avatar) {
      return 'background-image: url('+avatar+');';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Mind showing me an example of a simple method that uses the value and concetate the existing ones? Also, if I want to "add" a class (as I'm trying to do) what would be the best approach? And...How can they not include such an important feature... :/

Comment: This is correct. Also, for binding to native attributes such as styleor class the attribute binding syntax with the $ sign should be used. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was of great help!

Answer (score 1):

In 1.0, you must either enclose your bindings in tags with no spaces, or it be the full and only content of an attribute, i.e. `<hi so="{{then}}">{{there}}</hi>`.

Comment: Uhm okay, thank you. So how can I "add" classes etc? :o

Comment: A computed property would be my first idea, based on state in the element.